# mysql: /usr/local/lib/libssl.so.1.1: version `OPENSSL_1_1_1' not found (required by mysql)

Tags: mysql, wordpress, openssl

I recently updated and upgraded my Ubuntu 18.04 LTS running a Word Press site.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Evidently, the upgrade also included mysql which is locally running on the web-server. Now I get following error:

**mysql: /usr/local/lib/libssl.so.1.1: version `OPENSSL_1_1_1' not found (required by mysql)**

Any ideas how to go about fixing it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have met the same problem, and I fixed it on my ubuntu18.04.

I had found the same file at the path="/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.1" on my computer.
I backup the file and copy the same file from the mentioned path.

```sh
sudo mv /usr/local/lib/libssl.so.1.1 /usr/local/lib/libssl.so.1.1.old
sudo cp /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.1 /usr/local/lib/
```

then it will get error fllows:

```
mysql: libcrypto.so.1.1: version `OPENSSL_1_1_1' not found (required by libssl.so.1.1)
```

and do the same work

```
sudo mv /usr/local/lib/libcrypto.so.1.1 /usr/local/lib/libcrypto.so.1.1.old
sudo cp /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.1 /usr/local/lib/
```

then the problem had been worked out.

Comment: Thanks - although I fixed it by renaming the openssl 1.0.0 to .old and then installing openssl by compiling it. apt-get install didnt work for me. I believe your solution would have worked.